# Use jQuery click function to click data-target

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am stuck on getting the .click() function to select i the data-target attribute when loading the page with.

Comment: Can you give some code?

Comment: within the click callback use `$(this).data('target')` to get the `data-target` attribute. As you have not posted any code, i can just provide this.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('*[data-target="whatever"]').click(function(){

   // Whatever you want to execute after click

});
```

Answer (score 2):

He could also mean:

```
$('.selector').click(function(){

   // get this data-target
   var target = $(this).data("target");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery:

**HTML**

```
<div data-target="foo">CLICK THIS FOR FOO</div>
<div data-target="bar">CLICK THIS FOR BAR</div>
<div data-no-target="foo">NO TARGET</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].addEventListener( 'click', function(){
        alert(this.getAttribute('data-target'));
    });    
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3f11jcty/)